# remove all possible unwanted characters from python string at once

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, python-newspaper

I'm using python module `newspaper3k` and extracting article summary using its web url. As,

```
from newspaper import Article
article = Article('https://www.abcd....vnn.com/dhdhd')
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
text = article.summary
print (text)
```

Gives,

```
Often hailed as Hollywood\xe2\x80\x99s long standing, commercially successful filmmaker, Spielberg\xe2\x80\x99s lifetime gross, if you include his productions, reaches a mammoth\xc2\xa0$17.2 billion\xc2\xa0\xc2\xad\xe2\x80\x93 unadjusted for inflation.
\r\rThe original\xc2\xa0Jurassic Park\xc2\xa0($983.8 million worldwide), which released in 1993, remains Spielberg\xe2\x80\x99s highest grossing film.
Ready Player One,\xc2\xa0currently advancing at a running total of $476.1 million, has become Spielberg\xe2\x80\x99s seventh highest grossing film of his career.It will eventually supplant Aamir\xe2\x80\x99s 2017 blockbuster\xc2\xa0Dangal\xc2\xa0(1.29 billion yuan) if it achieves the Maoyan\xe2\x80\x99s lifetime forecast of 1.31 billion yuan ($208 million) in the PRC.
```

All I want to remove all unwanted characters like `\xe2\x80\x99s`. I'm avoiding to use multiple `replace` function. All I want something like:-

```
Often hailed as Hollywood long standing, commercially successful filmmaker, 
Spielberg lifetime gross, if you include his productions, reaches a 
mammoth $17.2 billion unadjusted for inflation.
The original Jurassic Park ($983.8 million worldwide), 
which released in 1993, remains Spielberg highest grossing film.
Ready Player One,currently advancing at a running total of $476.1 million, 
has become Spielberg seventh highest grossing film of his career.
It will eventually supplant Aamir 2017 blockbuster Dangal (1.29 billion yuan) 
if it achieves the Maoyan lifetime forecast of 1.31 billion yuan ($208 million) in the PRC
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid use of replace? If it is because of syntactic concerns, you can use a single regex statement that removes all substrings of the form \x--. or is it because of time complexity concerns(as removing k substrings in a string of length n takes O(n*k) time) ?

Comment: @AayushMahajan check edited question

Comment: Beware, just removing all non ascii characters could result in an incorrect text. For example `'\xc2\xa2'` is utf8 for `'\xa0'` the unicode U+00A0 or NO BREAK SPACE character. Removing it could concatenate 2 adjacent words...

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions:

```
import re
clear_str = re.sub(r'[\xe2\x80\x99s]', '', your_input)
```

`re.sub` replaces all occurences of a pattern in `your_input` with the 2nd argument. Pattern like `[abc]` matches either `a`, `b` or `c` character.

Comment: Oh, perhaps these characters of yours are substrings really, try with this pattern: `r'(\xe2|\x80|\x99s)'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `encode`/`decode` to get rid of every non-latin characters

```
data = text.decode('utf-8')
text = data.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')` to ignore all non ASCII characters.

If you need this text to do some sort of sentiment analysis, then you might also like to remove special characters like `\n`, `\r`, etc, which can be done by first escaping the escape characters, and then replacing them with the help of regex.

```
from newspaper import Article
import re
article = Article('https://www.abcd....vnn.com/dhdhd')
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
text = article.summary
text = text.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
text = str(text) #converts `\n` to `\\n` which can then be replaced by regex
text = re.sub('\\\.','',text) #Removes all substrings of form \\.
print (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The article was decoded incorrectly.  It likely had the wrong encoding specified on the website, but without a valid url in the question to reproduce the output that's difficult to prove.

The escape codes indicate utf8 was the correct encoding, so use the following to encode back to bytes directly (latin1 is a 1:1 mapping from the first 256 Unicode codepoints to bytes), then decode with utf8:

```
text = text.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Result:

> Often hailed as Hollywood’s long standing, commercially successful filmmaker, Spielberg’s lifetime gross, if you include his productions, reaches a mammoth $17.2 billion ­– unadjusted for inflation.
>
> The original Jurassic Park ($983.8 million worldwide), which released in 1993, remains Spielberg’s highest grossing film.
>   Ready Player One, currently advancing at a running total of $476.1 million, has become Spielberg’s seventh highest grossing film of his career.It will eventually supplant Aamir’s 2017 blockbuster Dangal (1.29 billion yuan) if it achieves the Maoyan’s lifetime forecast of 1.31 billion yuan ($208 million) in the PRC.